# How to execute action in child component after parent update

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on a Vue.js project where I need to execute some logic in the child component after the parent component has finished. In particular, the child component issues an event to the parent component to save some data. After that the parent component must communicate back to the child component and cause it to execute some logic (in this case to clear its own state).

```
<template>
    <div>
        <child-component @save="saveData">
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        saveData(event){

            $.post('/api', event)
                .done(function(data){
                    // signal to child to clear data state
                })
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

My question is, what is the proper way to handle this in Vue.js? I understand child components communicate to parents via events and parents communicate with child components via props. But from what I understand, just changing props won't cause any logic to be updated in the child component.

Comment: How about using vuex?

Comment: @Areg Vuex is not a rocket launcher that needs to be used at any given time. It suits a specific purpose (essentially passing data through a lot of components levels, hence "globally"). And you should always use the option that is most suited to it's purpose.

Comment: @kissu vuex is a rocket launcher

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting I found that passing a callback to the parent works best for my purpose. The child wraps the data, and a callback in an event which is then received by the parent. The parent can execute the callback in context of the child, after it is finished. I also found it has the added benefit of allowing multiple child components to be rendered in a loop. While this wasn't a requirement on my original question, it is certainly nice to have.

```js
Vue.component('child-component', {
  data: function() {
    return {
      id: this.childId,
      value: 'Hello World'
    };
  },
  props: ['childId'],
  methods: {
    saveData(){
      data = {
        id: this.id,
        value: this.value
      };
      callback = () => {alert('CHILD COMPONENT SAYS: Initial Value of Child ' + this.id  + ' Is: ' + this.value); this.clearData(); alert('CHILD COMPONENT SAYS: Final Value of Child ' + this.id  + ' Is: ' + this.value); };
      this.$emit('saveEvent', {data, callback})
    },
    clearData(){
      this.value = '';
    }
  },
  template: `<div>I Am Child {{ childId }} <button @click="saveData">Click Me To Save My Data</button></div>`
});

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {},
  methods: {
    saveData({data, callback}){
      debugger;
      alert('PARENT COMPONENT SAYS: Saving data...');
      callback();
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>I am the parent component</p>
      <child-component v-for="n in 5" :childId="n" :key="n" @saveEvent="saveData($event)" />
    </div>`
})
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the state in the parent **will** update the state in the child. So, if you update any props, this will be reactive and updated in the children properly.

You could add a `watch` (to the child component) on the passed props, especially if the given object do have changing data nested deeply thanks to `deep: true`.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch